# Tweaking pgfplot table

Tags: line-breaking, pgfplotstable

With `\pgfplotstabletypeset` and macro I have successfully made a new combined column including text from 3 columns with the create col command and `\edef` macro. I do not understand the full extent and opportunities of these commands as I have picked them up from other places on these forums. How can I then tweak the table to give me the following:

1. Add linebreaks in the combined column in the table so that text collected from sourcetable column “Publication” is placed on a new line within its new combined cell (I have inserted `\allowbreak` in the `\edef` macro but doesn’t help)
2. Change line spacing for a single line in the combined column (in example the line with data from source "Publication")
3. Define a string of text which should be in bold in the table every time it appears, in example “Strand TE”
4. Select only columns with a given string in column Cat to be included in final table, in example Cat = “A”

The final text will be imported from .csv file therefore I need to use `\pgfplotstabletypeset`

Code here:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}  

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash}m{1.5 cm}}    
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\arraybackslash}m{14 cm}}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    Cat, Author, Publication, Forum
    A, Ashraf H; Strand TE; Friesland S; Koyi H, Implementation of Lung Cancer CT Screening in the Nordic Countries., Acta Oncol. 2017:56:1249-57. doi: 10.1080/0284186X.2017.1329592
    B, Strand TE; Zare HK; Boico A; Radiloff D; Zhao Y; Irwin D, The novel combination of theophylline and bambuterol as a potential treatment of hypoxemia in humans., Can J Physiol Pharmacol. 2017 May 3. doi: 10.1139/cjpp-2016-0635.
    B, Chahal-Kummen M; Strand TE; Owe JO; Gulliksen E; Wagstaff AS., Aeromedical Evaluation for an F-16 Candidate with Incomplete Paraplegia, Aerospace Medicine and Human Performance Vol. 87 No. 11 November 2016
    A, Amini M; Hisdal J; Gjovaag T; Kapetanovic N; Strand TE; Owe JO; Horthe JR; Mirtaheri P., Near Infrared spectra in buccal tissue as a marker for detection of hypoxia, Aerosp Med Hum Perform. 2016:87:498-504
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    col sep=comma,
    header=has colnames,
    create on use/Combined/.style={
        create col/assign/.code={
            \edef\entry{
                \thisrow{Author}, \thisrow{Publication}, \allowbreak  \thisrow{Forum}
                    }
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry} 
        }
    },
    columns={Cat, Combined},
    columns/Kat/.style={column name=Category, column type=C},
    columns/Combined/.style={column name=Combined column, column type=D},  
    string type,
    end table=\end{longtable}
    ]{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

This implement all specifications; I've changed the 14cm to 8cm to fit to the page and also used `tabularx` as an inner tabular to get the required linebreaks. The filter is set for `B` but can be changed in the row predicate.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash}m{1.5 cm}}    
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\arraybackslash}m{10 cm}}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
Cat, Author, Publication, Forum
A, Ashraf H; Strand TE; Friesland S; Koyi H, Implementation of Lung Cancer CT Screening in the Nordic Countries., Acta Oncol. 2017:56:1249-57. doi: 10.1080/0284186X.2017.1329592
B, Strand TE; Zare HK; Boico A; Radiloff D; Zhao Y; Irwin D, The novel combination of theophylline and bambuterol as a potential treatment of hypoxemia in humans., Can J Physiol Pharmacol. 2017 May 3. doi: 10.1139/cjpp-2016-0635.
B, Chahal-Kummen M; Strand TE; Owe JO; Gulliksen E; Wagstaff AS., Aeromedical Evaluation for an F-16 Candidate with Incomplete Paraplegia, Aerospace Medicine and Human Performance Vol. 87 No. 11 November 2016
A, Amini M; Hisdal J; Gjovaag T; Kapetanovic N; Strand TE; Owe JO; Horthe JR; Mirtaheri P., Near Infrared spectra in buccal tissue as a marker for detection of hypoxia, Aerosp Med Hum Perform. 2016:87:498-504
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[
  col sep=comma,
  header=has colnames,
]{data.txt}\mytable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  create on use/Combined/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \edef\entry{\noexpand\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{@{}X@{}}\thisrow{Author}\noexpand\\[5mm]
                  \thisrow{Publication}, \thisrow{Forum}\noexpand\end{tabularx}}%
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
    }
  },
  begin table=\begin{longtable},
  end table=\end{longtable},
  columns={Cat, Combined},
  columns/Cat/.style={column name=Category, column type=C},
  columns/Combined/.style={column name=Combined column, column type=D,
                           string replace*={Strand TE}{\textbf{Strand TE}}},
  string type,
  row predicate/.code={\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Cat}\of\mytable%
                       \expandafter\if\pgfplotsretval B\else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]